# To what extent can we refactor unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, nunit, jasmine

When working with `Jasmine` testing framework, I have come across a code snippet where `expect` is written in a sub-function which is called in `it()`, but not in `it()` itself. The reason behind writing this is, they were trying to compare similar objects and they `refactored` test code and moved this `expect` to the sub-function. Now, we don't have `expect` in `it()` rather we have a method call which has `expect`.

```
describe("bla bla", function() { //for nunit, junit guys, this is testSuite()
    function somefunc() { //this is [test]
    //do some stuff and generate object
    expect(someObject).toEqual(otherObject); //expect is assert
}
   it("some case", function() {
       //do some stuff
       somefunc();
   });
   it("some other case", function() {
       //do some other stuff
       somefunc();
   });
});
```

Now, is this kind of test code encouragable? can we have `it()` without `expect` ?

Comment: Keep to the 3 A's pattern http://xp123.com/articles/3a-arrange-act-assert/, and ensure each stage is clear and readable. If somefunc() is actually assertExpected() I'd argue that's okay.

Comment: but, doesn't it impact the readability of test?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the two examples below are both readable. If assertExpected() did some kind of setup for `otherObject` the first example could be more readable.

```
describe("bla bla", function() { //for nunit, junit guys, this is testSuite()
    function assertExpected() { //this is [test]
      //do some stuff and generate object
      expect(someObject).toEqual(otherObject); //expect is assert
    }

   it("some case", function() {
       // Arrange
       var someObject;

       // Act
       someObject = testMethod('foo');

       // Assert
       assertExpected();
   });

   it("some other case", function() {
       // Arrange
       var otherObject, someObject = testMethod('foo');

       // Act
       someObject = testMethod('foo');

       // Assert
       assert(someObject(foo)).toEqual(otherObject);
   });
});
```

I think the deciding factor here should be deciding on a house style and sticking with it. There's no clear winner here and this question probably isn't a good question for SO.